# Link to anchor not yet loaded (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading comments with ajax in my website, and I'm sending to users notification with an anchor to the specific comment.

The anchor is not working, that piece of DOM isn't loaded yet.

How can I handle this? Maybe something "on ajax complete" ? I can do a script that launch "on ajax complete", but I don't know how to manage the anchor in the url.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax has a complete() callback that you can put code into. you can run location.hash = yourAnchorHash.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's complete or success callback depending on whether you only want your code to fire when the call is successful or always when the call is complete.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "yourURL",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: yourData,
                async: true,
                success: function (msg) {
                  //get stuff done when ajax call is successful
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                  //get stuff done when ajax call is complete
                }
            });
```